# What is needed to open up an MVC project on a remote server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web

I'm new to web development so please be kind. Anyway, I'm writing a web page in visual web developer 2012 and have hit a roadblock. I've got lots more experience with writing console applications. When writing one of those and you build the application, the bin folder is populated with the files that are required to run the application, most notable the .exe . But when I build the page all I get is .cshtml files, which when opened all it does is open the code in my web browser. I tried to get an answer on another web site but all that i got was "open it up on a web server". That doesn't make any sense to me. Please help.....

Answer (score 0):

You *open the project* locally on your workstation, as you would any other project.  But when you're ready to *publish* the project you would send it to a web server.

Visual Web Developer (being akin to Visual Studio, no?) *should* have a small built-in web server of some sort which it uses when you execute your project in debug mode.  (There are more details than that, but that statement alone should be true enough to get you debugging.)  That's fine for ongoing development work, but not for the resulting production application.

Analogous to installing a console application on a target workstation, you would need to publish your web application to a web server.  This server may *coincidentally* by the same workstation on which you develop the code, but that's not a requirement.

A "web server" in this case can be one of *many* things.  Your computer (running IIS, most likely), a server hosted somewhere, a service in the cloud, etc.  And "publishing" could mean any number of things as well.  Uploading the files, using built-in publishing tools in the IDE, even just committing the files to source control and allowing an automated publish service to fetch them (I do this a lot in Azure web sites).

Ultimately, the way you *execute* a web application that's been published isn't by double-clicking on a file anywhere.  The `.cshtml` files, as well as any other needed files (binaries, config files, images, style sheets, etc.) are stored on a web server somewhere and you would "run" the application by making a request to that web server, which takes the form of browsing to a URL in your web browser.